# Stack reverse poish calculator

Tags: c++, stack

basically I was supposed to do a reverse polish notation calculator within a stack. I follow a tutorial and based my code upon few algorithms that I found on the net. However, when I run the program the program doesn't print the calculations and I have no clue what it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool check_operator(string op);
bool check_operand(string op);
double operation(const string& input, stack<double>& calc);


int main()
{
    stack<double> calc;
    string input, choice;

    cout << "Welcome to this Post-Fix Notation calculator. Please select your choice"
    << endl << "1. Perform an operation" << endl << "2. Quit" << endl;

    cin >> choice;

    while (choice != "2") {
        cout << "Introduce your operation" << endl;
        cin >> input;
    double value;
    if (istringstream(input) >> value) {

        calc.push(value);

    }
    else if (check_operator(input)){ 

        operation(input, calc);

    }

        //cout << input << endl;

        cout << "Would you like to continue?" << endl << "1. Yes" << endl << "2. No" << endl;
        cin  >> choice;

    }


}


bool check_operator(string op) {
    if (op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "*" || op == "/")
        return true; 
    else 
    return false;//not an operator
}

bool check_operand(string op) {
    if (op >= "0" && op <= "9")
        return true;
    else
        return false;//not an operand
}

double operation(const string& input, stack<double>& calc) {
    double val1, val2, result;
    val1 = calc.top();
    calc.pop();

    val2 = calc.top();
    calc.pop();

    if (input == "+")
    {
        result = val2 + val1;
    }
    else if (input == "-") {
        result = val2 - val1;
    }
    else if (input == "*") {
        result = val2 * val1;
    }
    else if (input == "/" && val1 == 0) {
        cout << "Invalid input";
    }
    else if (input == "/" && val1 != 0) {
        result = val2 / val1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

    cout << result << endl;
    calc.push(result);
}
```

Can you help me to figure what is wrong with it?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: A general tip to simplify debugging and finding errors: [Find a simpler problem.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) This is usually accomplished by not writing whole programs or even whole functions in one go, but by writing a very small piece of code that can be easily tested. Once that small piece of code works, add the next small piece of code and test it. Continue until you have a fully working program. If there's an error or a problem, you know it must be in the last little piece of code you added, and makes it easier to debug just that little piece.